# С# Form buttons do not update; when they are updated

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, button, visualization

Together with a friend, we are trying to create a sea battle for playing on a local network, we made a field of buttons, created islands on it, you can set up ships and move them. But when we connected the form to our server, after requesting the package, the form stops drawing buttons, they store the correct data, but their visual update does not occur

Here are the pieces of code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Visible = false;
            comboBox2.Visible = false;
            button1.Visible = false;
            comboBox3.Visible = false;
            button2.Visible = true;
            SendPacket(PacketInfo.SendGameInfo);            
            Thread thread = new Thread(FightIsDone);
            thread.Start();
            State = GameState.Waiting;
        }
```

```
void FightIsDone()
        {            
            ReceivePacket();
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => GameUpdate()));
        }
        public void GameUpdate()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("!");
            State = GameState.Planing;
            foreach (Ship ship in Ships)
            {
                ship.UseModuls();
            }            
            SetShip(Ships);
            UpdateSight();            
            Draw();            
        }
```

The problem is here, this method changes the image of the button or its color, it works fine until the packet is sent to the server, but after receiving it, only the information is updated, and the appearance of the form does not change

```
public void Draw()
        {            
            foreach (CellButton Butt in Field)
            {
                if (Butt.Sigth)
                {
                    Butt.Image = null;
                    SetImage(Butt);
                }
                else
                {
                    Butt.BackColor = Color.Gray;                    
                    Butt.Image = null;
                }
            }            
        }
```

```
 public void SetImage(CellButton Butt)
        {
            switch (Butt.Entety)
            {
                case GameObject.Water: Butt.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue; break;
                case GameObject.Island: Butt.Image = GetObjectImage(GameObject.Island); break;
                case GameObject.Ship:
                    {
                        Butt.Image = Butt.modul.ModulImage;
                        break;
                    }
                case GameObject.Torpedo: Butt.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue; break;
                case GameObject.Fire: Butt.Image = GetObjectImage(GameObject.Fire); break;
            }            
        }
```

```
static void SendPacket(PacketInfo info) 
        {
            ms.Position = 0;
            switch (info)
            {              
                case PacketInfo.Connect:
                    writer.Write(0);
                    break;
                case PacketInfo.SendCoordinate:
                    writer.Write(1);
                    formatter.Serialize(ms, new Coordinate(5, 0));
                    break;
                case PacketInfo.LaunchSearch:
                    writer.Write(2);
                    writer.Write(Me.ID);
                    break;
                case PacketInfo.SendGameInfo:
                    writer.Write(3);
                    writer.Write(Me.ID);
                    List<Ship> shpooks = new List<Ship>();
                    foreach (Ship s in Ships)
                        if (s.PlayerID == Me.ID) shpooks.Add(s);
                    formatter.Serialize(ms, shpooks);
                    break;

            }
            socket.Send(ms.GetBuffer());
        }
```

```
static int ReceivePacket()
        {
            ms.Position = 0;
            socket.Receive(ms.GetBuffer());
            int code = reader.ReadInt32();
            switch (code)
            {
                case 0:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Catch");
                        Console.WriteLine(ms.ToString());
                        bool IsConected = reader.ReadBoolean();
                        if (IsConected)
                        {
                            Me.ID = reader.ReadInt32();
                            return 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 2: 
                    {
                        return 1;
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        Cell[,] cells = (Cell[,])formatter.Deserialize(ms);
                        for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
                            for (int j = 0; j < Hight; j++)
                            {
                                Field[i, j] = new CellButton(new Coordinate(i, j));
                                Field[i, j].SetCell(cells[i, j]);                                                               
                            }
                        Ships.Clear();
                        Ships.AddRange((List<Ship>)formatter.Deserialize(ms));
                        break;
                    }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

This is the form before calling Draw():
[image: This is the form before calling Draw()]

This is how the form looks after calling Draw():
[image: This is how the form looks after calling Draw()]

And so, after a request to the server and method Draw():
[image: And so, after a request to the server and method Draw()]

I spent a lot of time finding solutions, methods like Form.Update() and Form.Refresh() don't help

Comment: You'll need to use the GUI thread to update the interface. Have a look at (e. g.) [`Control.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Am I calling for a form, or is it necessary for each button?

Comment: I'm not that versed in WinForms, but I think it's common to do it per control.

Comment: Ok, i'll try now

Comment: The problem was in receiving the package, I did not notice that I was creating new buttons there, although it was necessary to replace the old ones, anyway thanks for the advice

Comment: Glad that you figured it out! To be honest you posted a lot of code and I just guessed at what I perceive to be the most common problem with multithreading and GUI. Maybe next time you're able to post a more condensed problem - have a look at [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Henceforth, I will be brief, here I just did not know where to look for the error, and simply pulled out potential sites, where there may be an error
Thanks for the link.